# Linq с условием в Include

Tags: c#, linq

Имеется класс

```
public class Item {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsOutdated { get; set; }

    public int Parent_Id { get; set; }
    public Item Parent { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Item> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Необходимо вывести все экземпляры этого класса деревом. Использую такое выражение

```
var result = items.Include(x => x.Children.Select(y => y.Children))
.Where(z => z.Parent_Id == null);
```

Теперь в полученном дереве необходимо убрать все элементы, у которых **IsOutdated = true**. Как это сделать?

Comment: Перед Include добавить Where нельзя?

Comment: @Андрей а разве есть разница? После он стоит или перед, он будет фильтровать только записи верхнего уровня, вложенное не тронет

Comment: Ааа, ну а так не работает: `.Include(x => x.Children.Where(...` ?

Comment: Кстати, а куда потом вы это всё выводите? У вас по сути `Include` не нужен, так как таблица та же самая. По идее вам достаточно взять `items.Where(...)` и всё, в каждом `Item` ссылка на родителя есть, так что проблем построить дерево я не вижу

Comment: @Андрей требуется, чтобы структура вывода была такая: { Id: 1, Name: 'first', Children: { Id: 1, Name: 'FirstChildOfFirst' } }, так что такой вариант не подходит

Answer (score 1):

Думаю это вам должно помочь :

```
    var result = items.Include(x => x.Children.Select(y => y.Children))
.Where(z => z.Parent_Id == null && z.IsOutdated == false);
```

`IdOutDated` == `false` , в том случае если мы хотим получать только свежие данные

Поподробней можно найти на англоязычных форумах где описывается как можно совместить несколько условий в `Where`[тыц](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289565/two-conditions-checking-in-where-clause-using-linq-2-entites) и [тыц](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45725104/using-multiple-clauses-in-where?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Ну и поскольку таблица у нас всего одна  - то больше смысла будет в таком запросе :

```
var reslut = items.Where(z => z.Parent_Id == null && z.IsOutdated == false);
```

Comment: Среди дочерних элементов-то всё равно останутся те, у которых `IsOutdated = true`

Comment: @Андрей теперь должно сработать - я просто вместо AND заюзал OR не к месту)

Comment: Нет, такой способ не подходит, нужно чтобы свойство Children содержало дочерние элементы

Comment: @сергей тамбовцев, у вас в вопросе указано как получить это дерево и вы спросили как добавить дополнительное условие в `Where`  . Если вам важен факт наличия у `Children` дочерних элементов то возьмите первый,изначальный  вариант моего ответа - в полученном дереве как раз будут все элементы где свойство `IsOutdated` == `false`

Comment: @clyde Вам Андрей выше писал, почему первый способ работать не будет. Дочерние элементы не фильтруются таким условием

Comment: @сергей тамбовцев , я уже давно исправил условие,так как в первом варианте - там был `OR` вместо `AND` . Теперь точно должно работать

Comment: @clyde ну я проверил, не работает. Фильтрация не применяется к дочерним записям, хоть с OR, хоть с AND